# Argparse URL type

Tags: python, argparse

Let's have a simple argparser with one argument which shall represent URL.

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def my_url(arg):
"""
Some url validation

"""

parser = ArgumentParser(
    description="foobar"
)
parser.add_argument(
    "-u",
    "--url",
    type=my_url,
    help="foobar",
)
```

Is there ready up to take function to validate if argument is URL in order to omit `my_url` custom validation function?

Comment: `type` takes a function, not a `datatype` specification.  The common `type` values like `int` and `float` work because they are functions, not `datatypes`.  So if you can't find a function in a library like `urllib.parse` that does what you want, you have to write your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) function from `urllib.parse` & check if it was able to pull out all the required components from the URL:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse


def my_url(arg):
    url = urlparse(arg)
    if all((url.scheme, url.netloc)):  # possibly other sections?
        return arg  # return url in case you need the parsed object
    raise ArgumentTypeError('Invalid URL')
```

Result:

```
parser.parse_args(['-u', 'http://locahost:2000'])  # pass
parser.parse_args(['-u', 'http/locahost:2000'])  # Invalid URL
parser.parse_args(['-u', 'thisisurl'])  # Invalid URL
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer ! :)
My only concern is I don't want to use my custom validation function (`to omit my_url`). I'm looking some predefined, ready to take object.